# Editing file Variable Product Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

Hi, i want to editing my wp-admin variable product in woocommerce, i want to insert **weight**(textbox) script into my plugin, does anyone know where the file is to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to render field:

```
function RenderFieldsAfterPrices($loop, $variation_data, $variation) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input([    
        'id'    => 'my_weight[' . $loop . ']',
        'class' => 'short',
        'wrapper_class'=> 'variable-my_weight form-row form-row-first',
        'label' => __( 'My weight', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value' => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'my_weight', true ),
    ]);
}
add_action('woocommerce_variation_options_pricing', 'RenderFieldsAfterPrices', 10, 3);
```

This part is for saving value:

```
function SaveProductVariationFields($variation_id, $i = null) {
    if ($i !== null) {
        $MyWeight= $_POST['my_weight'][$i];
        update_post_meta( $variation_id,'my_weight', $MyWeight);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'SaveProductVariationFields', 10, 2);
add_action('woocommerce_new_product_variation', 'SaveProductVariationFields', 10, 2);
```

Note: play with 'class' and 'wrapper_class' to align new field, see documentation about woocommerce_wp_text_input().